# Why does the jQuery 'nth-child' selector not work inside GreaseMonkey (0.8)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I believe jQuery's :nth-child selector doesn't work inside GreaseMonkey 0.8.
(At the bottom is a quick GM script to test this.)
Why is this?
Is this a known limitation from working inside GreaseMonkey?
Can anyone recommend a way around this?

Also, why is it that *some* (definitely not all)  jQuery queries run *much* slower inside GreaseMonkey, I don't have a quick benchmark test right now, but I've noticed it often as I was building [a pretty complex GM script that relied heavily in GM](http://elzr.com/posts/backbars-on-social-link-sites). I would run my code outside GM, in Firebug, and things would be snappy, while inside GM the browser was brought to its knees. I know that's vague but I was wondering if there are some broad architectural reasons in GM or jQuery why this would be the case.

Thanks!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Test of nth-child
// @namespace     http://elzr.com
// @description   nth-child doesn't work in jQuery within GreaseMonkey
// @include       http://en.wikipedia.org/*
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js
// @author        Eliazar Parra elzr.com
// ==/UserScript==
//
// For detailed info and screenshots see http://elzr.com/posts/wikipedia-backbars

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('a:nth-child(1)').length)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to how GreaseMonkey uses [XPCNativeWrapper](http://wiki.greasespot.net/XPCNativeWrapper)s for security.  They definitely add overhead, and might be bumping up against JQuery.